# Regex to add additional lines of text between some lines?

Tags: regex, replace

Actually, I have a very complex problem, but I have narrowed it down here to the most essential part with some dummy-data.

Say I have the following text:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaaa
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaa
a
```

What I would like to do is, FOR EXAMPLE when a line of 4 a's is followed by a line of 1 a. I'd like to add a line of 3 a's after the line of 4, and add a line of 2 a's after the line of 3. So the result would be this:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaa
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
```

I have tried the folowing regex in editpad pro:

```
find: \r?\n(a*)aa\r?\n\1\r?\n
repl: \n\1aa\n\1a\n\1\n
```

But this only works when the next line has exactly 2 a's less than the previous one.. I know I could write a bunch of regular expressions like the one above, to work for difference of 2 a's, 3 a's, 4 a's, 5 a's and so on. But I'd like to have only one regex. I don't mind if I would have to run that regex multiple times though..

Comment: In your example, you said, "when a line of 4 a's is followed by a line of 1 a", but you said later, "But this only works when the next line has exactly 2 a's less than the previous one". I don't understand. You should rephrase your question clearly. I'm sure many people here confused like me.

Comment: yeah, it was an example. What i meant is that if i have 4 a's folowed by 1 a, i want to add a line of 3 a's and a line of 2 a's between those lines. So what i want to do is add lines with a's so that every line has exactly one a less than the previous one, except if the line has more a's than the previous one. So what i meant by "this only works when the next line has exactly 2 a's less than the previous one" is that i had a script that would add a line of 3 a's between a line of 4a's folowed by a line of 2 a's. I know it's not formulated very well but just look at the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution myself. Seems like I was very close, just overdid it a bit with the line breaks in the beginning.

```
find: (a*)aa\r?\n\1\r?\n
repl: \1aa\n\1a\n\1\n
```

This works after i repeatedly klick 'replace all' in editpad pro. I would like to have a solution where i need to run the replace all only once, so if there's any further thoughts, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you save your dummy data in a file called `file`, save the following [gawk(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gawk_%28GNU_package%29) program as a file called `runme` and invoke it from the shell as `gawk -f runme file`, it should result in your desired output.

Note that the program prints newly produced lines as a series of hashes instead of a's in order to illustrate the additions.

```
BEGIN { }

{
    if (NR==1) { print $0; oldrec = $0; }

    if (NR>1) {
            levelsdiff = length(oldrec) - length($0);

            if (levelsdiff>1) { 
                    newrecs = levelsdiff - 1;
                    i = 1;
                    while (newrecs>0) {
                            newline = "";
                            hashes = length(oldrec) - i;
                            while (hashes!=0) {
                                    newline = newline "#";
                                    hashes--;
                            }
                            print newline;
                            i++; newrecs--;
                    }
            }

            if (levelsdiff<1) { 
                    newrecs = -levelsdiff - 1;
                    i = 1;
                    while (newrecs>0) {
                            newline = "";
                            hashes = length(oldrec) + i;
                            while (hashes!=0) {
                                    newline = newline "#";
                                    hashes--;
                            }
                            print newline;
                            i++; newrecs--;
                    }
            }

            print $0;
            oldrec = $0;
    }
}

END { }
```

Outputs:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaaa
####
###
##
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
#####
aaaa
###
##
a
```

Comment: that's great, but doesn't involve regex. I'm looking for a regular expression to use in editpad pro